# Want to remove outer array of json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

This is my json data and I want to remove the outer array.

```
   [ 
       [ 
          { 
             "name":"name",
             "zip_code":"50700",
             "state":"state",
             "country":"country"
          }
       ]
    ]
```

I want like that

```
  [ 
      { 
         "name":"name",
         "zip_code":"50700",
         "state":"state",
         "country":"country"
      }
   ]
```

Comment: So parse it and get the `[0]`th element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply get the first element of the array, so [0] of the array.

```js
// If you have your array
const myArray =   [ 
       [ 
          { 
             "name":"name",
             "zip_code":"50700",
             "state":"state",
             "country":"country"
          }
       ]
    ]

// This will  give you what you want.
myArray[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the JSON to not return a nested array, just target the 0th index of the array. Code example:

```
var jsonData = [
    [
        {
            Name: 'John Doe'
        }
    ]
]

var strippedJsonData = jsonData[0];
```